# Spaces before and after br tag

Tags: html

Is it correct to have spaces before and after `<br>`?

For instance, what option is better? does it really matter?:

```
<p>first line<br>second line<br>third line</p>

<p>first line<br>
second line<br>
third line</p>

<p>first line
<br>
second line
<br>
third line</p>
```

Comment: Whatever you think is most readable. =)

Comment: I think for something as minute as this, it's really up to you. The end result is the same.

Comment: if this is for work and you have a pain in the ass boss, ask them first

Comment: Spaces add more characteres to your html file, that will make it slower to load for people who will visit your website. Multiply the spaces by the number of <br> tags, and multiply again by the number of pages your website has.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez I'm quite sure any browser will compress and remove extra spaces (and with spaces we are all apparently refering to line breaks?). Even if they didn't it would have to be a **huge** amount to make an actual impact :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't really matter functionality wise.

It's just for readability.

Personally, I like the second one because it makes it clear and distinct where each `br` is supposed to be.

Whichever you choose, stick with it and keep it consistent to make readability of your code easy.

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter.

I personally use the following syntax to see where I have (or have not) inserted newlines, but you should use what suits you depending on what you want. Code readability is usually a good choice.

```
line1
<br>line2
<br>line3
```